# How to Read First n Amount of Structs Variable in External File - C

Tags: c

I'm trying to run a program wherein, the user inputs a number of employees to read and the program displays the first n employees.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct employee {
    int id;
    char name[50];
    float salary;
}
struct employee e;
adddata(){
        FILE *fp;
        fp=fopen("record.txt","a");
        printf("        Employee Name : ");
        scanf("%s",e.name);
        printf("        ID :");
        scanf("%d",&e.id);
        printf("        Salary :");
        scanf("%f",e.salary);
        fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
        fwrite(&e,sizeof(e),1,fp);
        fclose(fp);
}
get(){
        int n;
        printf("amount to display: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("record.txt", "r");
        //code to get and display first n employees
        //e.g. n = 3; displays employee 1, 2, 3
}
int main(){
    int opt;
    printf("1 - add data \n 2 - get data");
    scanf("%d", &opt);
    switch(opt){
    case 1 : adddata();
    break;
    case 2 : get();
    }
}
```

content of the external text:

```
id        name        salary

1       John Doe      10000.00
2       Kyle Smith    15000.00
3       Ron Adams     20000.00
4       Alice Wilde   21000.00
5       Zoe Jordan    18000.00
```

How do you read it (not line by line but by struct variable)?

Comment: Do you want to store those recods in an array of struct variable?

Comment: Reading line by line and parsing it into struct variables is the usual way to do it. There's no standard library AFAIK to read from a text file straight into a struct. What's wrong with the line by line approach?

Comment: "How to Read ..." "but by struct variable", Nope, not unless it is written that way.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion about whether it's to be simply displayed or parsed and stored in a struct array. Clarification needed, because parsing the format is another matter than just calling printf on each line. Also, it's a good idea to actually make a serious attempt at coding it. The code is just a stub, so it feels like a "write it for me" sort of question currently... See [how do I ask homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Suggest opening the file in `main()` and pass the open `FILE*` pointer as a parameter to `get()`. If the file cannot be opened in the caller, no sense in making the function call. Also, avoid *hardcoded* filenames -- especially buried in functions. Instead use `argv` to pass the filename as an argument to `main()`. Also, suggest declaring a buffer (e.g. `char buf[512];` and read `int count = 0; while (count < n && fgets (buf, 512, fileptr)) { /* if parse id, name, salary, output, count++ */ }`. You can parse in 2 steps, with `sscanf` into `id` and `rest`, then manually separate `salary`.

Comment: Until you have the code that writes the file available for study, or you have a specification of how the file is written, you can't easily read it.  The intention is probably that the data is written using `fwrite()` and therefore should be read using `fread()`, but guessing is dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Given your addition showing you are writing the structures to your file in binary mode changes the character of your original question quite a bit. Rather than being one of read and parsing values from the text file as shown in your original question, it become one of simply reading a given number of structures, all of fixed size, from a binary file.

Since the original question indicated a read and parse of text, that will provide an opportunity for doing both while answering your question in total. So let's read and parse the original text you provided, then write a binary file containing the structures and then read from that file and display the output for the requested number of employees. (adding any header information you like to the output is left to you)

**Commandment No. 6 For C Programmers - "ye be warned..."**

First, your `adddata()` function is horribly fragile and a recipe for invoking *Undefined Behavior* on an innocent errant keystroke. You cannot use any input function properly (any function for that matter) without ***checking the return***. Lest ye violate [Commandment No. 6 of Henry Spencer's 10 Commandments for C Programmers](http://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html).

**Avoid Magic-Numbers & Hardcoded Filenames**

Additionally, don't use *Magic-Numbers* or *Hardcoded Filenames* in your code. If you need a constant, `#define` one (or more) and pass the filename to read from as an argument to `main()` or take it as input. For example:

```
#define MAXC 512        /* max characters for read buffer */
#define MAXN  50        /* max characters in name */

struct employee {
    int id;
    char name[MAXN];
    float salary;
};
```

and

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int n, nemp;    /* n for user input, nemp for number read from file */
    char ofn[MAXC], /* buffer to hold output file name for writing bin file */
        *p = ofn;   /* pointer to output file name buffer to swap extensions */
    FILE *fp;       /* file pointer */
    struct employee e[MAXN] = {{ .id = 0 }};    /* array of MAXN employee */

    if (argc < 2 ) {    /* validate 1 argument given for filename */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input,\n"
                        "usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(fp = fopen (argv[1], "r"))) { /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
```

**Original Question Text File Read**

On to handling your data. For your original data posted as text, were you faced with reading and parsing the data into your `struct employee`, you simply ignore all lines that do not begin with `isdigit()`.

Then to extract the information, you would basically work from the ends to the middle, reading the `id` and saving the number of characters that took. You would then backup from the end of the line until your first whitespace character (using `strrchr()`) and then convert the `salary` to `float. All that is left is scanning forward from the end of`id`until the first non-whitespace character is found, and then backing up from the space before`salary`until the first non-whitespace character is found. What is left between is the`name`which you can copy with`memcpy()` (don't forget to *nul-terminate).

Putting that together in a `readtext()` function that takes an open `FILE*` stream pointer, a pointer to the array of `struct employee` to fill (which is presumed large enough to hold the data read from the file -- you should add an additional validation by passing the max size as another parameter), and finally the number of employees to read. You could do something similar to:

```
/** read text file as shown in question into array of struct */
int readtext (FILE *fp, struct employee *emp, int n)
{
    int nemp = 0;       /* number of employees read */
    char buf[MAXC];     /* buffer to hold each line (don't skimp on size) */
    struct employee tmp = { .id = 0 };  /* temp struct to fill */

    while (nemp < n && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) { /* read each line */
        char *p, *ep;           /* pointer & end-pointer to use in parsing */
        int offset;             /* offset (no. of chars for id) */

        if (!isdigit (*buf))    /* if 1st char not digit, get next line */
            continue;
        /* if no successful convertion to int for id, get next line */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d%n", &tmp.id, &offset) != 1)
            continue;
        /* if space before salary or no conversion to float, get next line */
        if (!(ep = strrchr (buf, ' ')) || sscanf (ep, "%f", &tmp.salary) != 1)
            continue;

        p = buf + offset;       /* skip whitespace until start of name */
        while (isspace (*p))
            p++;

        do                      /* backup until last char in name found */
            ep--;
        while (ep > p && isspace(*ep));
        ep++;                   /* advance 1 past last char in name */

        memcpy (tmp.name, p, ep - p);   /* copy name to tmp.name */
        tmp.name[ep - p] = 0;           /* nul-terminate tmp.name */

        emp[nemp++] = tmp;  /* assign tmp to array, increment nemp */
    }

    return nemp;    /* return number of employees read into array */
}
```

And you would call it from main to fill your array of struct `e` as:

```
    ...
    fputs ("amount to display: ", stdout);  /* prompt */
    fflush (stdout);                        /* optional (but recommended) */
    if (scanf ("%d", &n) != 1) {            /* validate integer input */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    if ((nemp = readtext(fp, e, n)) != n)   /* if less than n read, warn */
        fprintf (stderr, "\nwarning: less than %d employees found.\n\n", n);
    fclose (fp);                        /* close file */
    ...
```

You can check you have the information you need by simply outputting the data:

```
    putchar ('\n');                 /* add newline before output */
    for (int i = 0; i < nemp; i++)  /* output employees read from file */
        printf ("%3d  %-20s  %.2f\n", e[i].id, e[i].name, e[i].salary);
```

The rest deals with writing data to your binary file that can then be read as your updated question indicates is the true problem. Both writing and then reading back from the binary file are simple calls to `fwrite` and `fread`. You can make functions for each, but that is left to you.

**Writing Binary File To Use With Updated Question**

Since we are writing the binary data from the information read from the text file, all that need to happen is to write the information out under a new filename. Simply swapping file extensions from `".txt"` to `".bin"` is a simple way to distinguish the files. If there is no extension on the input file, then simply add the `".bin"` extension to the end. (You should also add additional validations that the filename will fit in the space provided by `ofn` -- that is also left to you)

For this example we simply find the last `'.'` and consider everything to the right to be the file extension. This can be expanded upon as needed. A simple implementation would be:

```
    /* form output filename by changing extension to ".bin" */
    if ((p = strrchr (argv[1], '.')) == NULL)   /* if no last '.' in argv[1] */
        strcpy (ofn, argv[1]);                  /* copy all to ofn */
    else {  /* otherwise */
        memcpy (ofn, argv[1], p - argv[1]);     /* copy up to last '.' to ofn */
        ofn[p - argv[1]] = 0;                   /* nul-terminate */
    }
    strcat (ofn, ".bin");                       /* concatenate .bin extension */
```

With the output filename now formed, simply write the structures out, and close the file stream (*note:* ***always validate close-after-write*** to catch any errors in flushing the file stream that would not have been caught by your validation of `fwrite`)

```
    /* open/validate output file open for writing */
    if (!(fp = fopen (ofn, "wb"))) {
        perror ("fopen-idnamesal.bin");
        return 1;
    }

    /* write array to output file in binary */
    if (fwrite (e, sizeof *e, nemp, fp) != (size_t)nemp) {
        fputs ("error: short write to binary.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    if (fclose (fp) == EOF) {           /* always validate close-after-write */
        perror ("fclose-after-write");
        return 1;
    }
```

**Reading `struct employee` From Binary File**

Now we have a binary file containing your structures that we can work with to answer your updated question. While you can use your array-of-struct to read the data into, since you do not know how many `struct employee` you will read, this is traditionally where you would allocate a block of memory of sufficient size to hold the number of `struct employee` entered by the user using `malloc()`. This give you the ability to size your storage at run-time to the exact amount needed to hold your data. It is simple to do, but follow *Commandment No. 6*, e.g.

```
    /* allocate block of storage to hold data read from binary file */
    struct employee *empfrombin = malloc (nemp * sizeof *empfrombin);
    if (!empfrombin) {
        perror ("malloc-empfrombin");
        return 1;
    }
```

With a block of memory of sufficient size to hold the number of `struct employee` entered by the user, simply read that number of struct from your binary file into the new block with a single call to `fread` and close the file (no need to validate close-after-read). You can then output the information in the same manner as done above:

```
    /* read/validate struct data from binary file into newly allocated blockm */
    if (fread (empfrombin, sizeof *empfrombin, nemp, fp) != (size_t)nemp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file read failed - '%s'.\n", ofn);
        return 1;
    }
    fclose (fp);    /* close file */

    /* output employees from newly allocated/filled block of memory */
    fprintf (stdout, "\nemployees read from binary file '%s'\n\n", ofn);
    for (int i = 0; i < nemp; i++)
        printf ("%3d  %-20s  %.2f\n", 
                empfrombin[i].id, empfrombin[i].name, empfrombin[i].salary);
```

Lastly, in any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed. So simply `free()` your block of memory and you are done:

```
    free (empfrombin);  /* don't forget to free what you have allocated */
}
```

Putting it altogether, the entire example covering your original and update question would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for malloc/free */
#include <string.h>     /* for strrchr, memcpy */
#include <ctype.h>      /* for isspace, isdigit */

#define MAXC 512        /* max characters for read buffer */
#define MAXN  50        /* max characters in name */

struct employee {
    int id;
    char name[MAXN];
    float salary;
};

/** read text file as shown in question into array of struct */
int readtext (FILE *fp, struct employee *emp, int n)
{
    int nemp = 0;       /* number of employees read */
    char buf[MAXC];     /* buffer to hold each line (don't skimp on size) */
    struct employee tmp = { .id = 0 };  /* temp struct to fill */

    while (nemp < n && fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) { /* read each line */
        char *p, *ep;           /* pointer & end-pointer to use in parsing */
        int offset;             /* offset (no. of chars for id) */

        if (!isdigit (*buf))    /* if 1st char not digit, get next line */
            continue;
        /* if no successful convertion to int for id, get next line */
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d%n", &tmp.id, &offset) != 1)
            continue;
        /* if space before salary or no conversion to float, get next line */
        if (!(ep = strrchr (buf, ' ')) || sscanf (ep, "%f", &tmp.salary) != 1)
            continue;

        p = buf + offset;       /* skip whitespace until start of name */
        while (isspace (*p))
            p++;

        do                      /* backup until last char in name found */
            ep--;
        while (ep > p && isspace(*ep));
        ep++;                   /* advance 1 past last char in name */

        memcpy (tmp.name, p, ep - p);   /* copy name to tmp.name */
        tmp.name[ep - p] = 0;           /* nul-terminate tmp.name */

        emp[nemp++] = tmp;  /* assign tmp to array, increment nemp */
    }

    return nemp;    /* return number of employees read into array */
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int n, nemp;    /* n for user input, nemp for number read from file */
    char ofn[MAXC], /* buffer to hold output file name for writing bin file */
        *p = ofn;   /* pointer to output file name buffer to swap extensions */
    FILE *fp;       /* file pointer */
    struct employee e[MAXN] = {{ .id = 0 }};    /* array of MAXN employee */

    if (argc < 2 ) {    /* validate 1 argument given for filename */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input,\n"
                        "usage: %s filename\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(fp = fopen (argv[1], "r"))) { /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    fputs ("amount to display: ", stdout);  /* prompt */
    fflush (stdout);                        /* optional (but recommended) */
    if (scanf ("%d", &n) != 1) {            /* validate integer input */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    if ((nemp = readtext(fp, e, n)) != n)   /* if less than n read, warn */
        fprintf (stderr, "\nwarning: less than %d employees found.\n\n", n);
    fclose (fp);                        /* close file */

    putchar ('\n');                 /* add newline before output */
    for (int i = 0; i < nemp; i++)  /* output employees read from file */
        printf ("%3d  %-20s  %.2f\n", e[i].id, e[i].name, e[i].salary);

    /* form output filename by changing extension to ".bin" */
    if ((p = strrchr (argv[1], '.')) == NULL)   /* if no last '.' in argv[1] */
        strcpy (ofn, argv[1]);                  /* copy all to ofn */
    else {  /* otherwise */
        memcpy (ofn, argv[1], p - argv[1]);     /* copy up to last '.' to ofn */
        ofn[p - argv[1]] = 0;                   /* nul-terminate */
    }
    strcat (ofn, ".bin");                       /* concatenate .bin extension */

    /* open/validate output file open for writing */
    if (!(fp = fopen (ofn, "wb"))) {
        perror ("fopen-idnamesal.bin");
        return 1;
    }

    /* write array to output file in binary */
    if (fwrite (e, sizeof *e, nemp, fp) != (size_t)nemp) {
        fputs ("error: short write to binary.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    if (fclose (fp) == EOF) {           /* always validate close-after-write */
        perror ("fclose-after-write");
        return 1;
    }

    /* allocate block of storage to hold data read from binary file */
    struct employee *empfrombin = malloc (nemp * sizeof *empfrombin);
    if (!empfrombin) {
        perror ("malloc-empfrombin");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(fp = fopen (ofn, "rb"))) {    /* open/validate binary file */
        perror ("fopen-ofn-rb");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read/validate struct data from binary file into newly allocated blockm */
    if (fread (empfrombin, sizeof *empfrombin, nemp, fp) != (size_t)nemp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file read failed - '%s'.\n", ofn);
        return 1;
    }
    fclose (fp);    /* close file */

    /* output employees from newly allocated/filled block of memory */
    fprintf (stdout, "\nemployees read from binary file '%s'\n\n", ofn);
    for (int i = 0; i < nemp; i++)
        printf ("%3d  %-20s  %.2f\n", 
                empfrombin[i].id, empfrombin[i].name, empfrombin[i].salary);

    free (empfrombin);  /* don't forget to free what you have allocated */
}
```

(**note:** try and add the additional validations mentioned in the paragraphs above to ensure you can read no more data from the text file than you have available array storage for)

**Original Text Input File Used**

```
$ cat dat/idnamesal.txt
id        name        salary

1       John Doe      10000.00
2       Kyle Smith    15000.00
3       Ron Adams     20000.00
4       Alice Wilde   21000.00
5       Zoe Jordan    18000.00
```

**Resulting Binary File Written**

```
$ hexdump -C dat/idnamesal.bin
00000000  01 00 00 00 4a 6f 68 6e  20 44 6f 65 00 00 00 00  |....John Doe....|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 40 1c 46 02 00 00 00  |.........@.F....|
00000040  4b 79 6c 65 20 53 6d 69  74 68 00 00 00 00 00 00  |Kyle Smith......|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000070  00 00 00 00 00 60 6a 46  03 00 00 00 52 6f 6e 20  |.....`jF....Ron |
00000080  41 64 61 6d 73 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |Adams...........|
00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000000b0  00 40 9c 46 04 00 00 00  41 6c 69 63 65 20 57 69  |.@.F....Alice Wi|
000000c0  6c 64 65 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |lde.............|
000000d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000000e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 10 a4 46  |...............F|
000000f0  05 00 00 00 5a 6f 65 20  4a 6f 72 64 61 6e 00 00  |....Zoe Jordan..|
00000100  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000120  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 a0 8c 46              |...........F|
0000012c
```

**Example Use/Output**

Read from text format shown, write binary file of `struct employee` and read from binary file and display all `5` employees.

```
$ ./bin/readidnamesal dat/idnamesal.txt
amount to display: 5

  1  John Doe              10000.00
  2  Kyle Smith            15000.00
  3  Ron Adams             20000.00
  4  Alice Wilde           21000.00
  5  Zoe Jordan            18000.00

employees read from binary file 'dat/idnamesal.bin'

  1  John Doe              10000.00
  2  Kyle Smith            15000.00
  3  Ron Adams             20000.00
  4  Alice Wilde           21000.00
  5  Zoe Jordan            18000.00
```

Read less than all:

```
$ ./bin/readidnamesal dat/idnamesal.txt
amount to display: 1

  1  John Doe              10000.00

employees read from binary file 'dat/idnamesal.bin'

  1  John Doe              10000.00
```

Attempt to read more employees than exist in file:

```
$ ./bin/readidnamesal dat/idnamesal.txt
amount to display: 100

warning: less than 100 employees found.


  1  John Doe              10000.00
  2  Kyle Smith            15000.00
  3  Ron Adams             20000.00
  4  Alice Wilde           21000.00
  5  Zoe Jordan            18000.00

employees read from binary file 'dat/idnamesal.bin'

  1  John Doe              10000.00
  2  Kyle Smith            15000.00
  3  Ron Adams             20000.00
  4  Alice Wilde           21000.00
  5  Zoe Jordan            18000.00
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. While your question changed a bit, both the text operations from the original and then binary operations from the update question are *"bread-and-butter"* operations you will carry out time and again, so you may as well make friends with both.

Answer (score 0):

```
int get()
{
    int n,fd;
    struct employee emp;

    printf("amount to display: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    fd = open("record.txt", 0666);
    while(n--) {
        if(read(fd,&emp,sizeof(emp)) != sizeof(emp)) {
            return -1;
        }
        print_employee(&emp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```